# How to discard (trim) double inverted quotes in CSV file on data prep?

Tags: data-wrangling, google-cloud-dataprep, trifacta

I'm dealing with a csv file that contains double inverted quotes (since the data has commas in it). But Google sheets do not show me the double-quotes and hence i'm able to `split` the column by a delimiter (space in this case) properly, to retrieve its first word. The initial column values can be seen in the picture below.

[image: Google Sheet view]

However, in Data Prep when i upload the csv file, the column's double quotes are considered as a value and it causes extra work (if at all possible) in handling the resulting split data.

Is there a way in Data Prep where we can have the data displayed as in Google Sheets ?

[image: Data Prep view]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `Is there a way in Data Prep where we can have the data displayed as in Google Sheets ?`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry for late reply. Sure. What i meant to say is that, this same data when uploaded to Google sheets does not show the Quotes eg: Philips 0.5 W. Not like Dataprep that shows "Philip 0.5 W"

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your goal. Can I ask you about the relationship between your 2 sample images and `What i meant to say is that, this same data when uploaded to Google sheets does not show the Quotes eg: Philips 0.5 W. Not like Dataprep that shows "Philip 0.5 W"`?

Comment: @Tanaike See the first row for the column Product Name in the screen shot. You can see a product "Philips....".  But you also see a quotation at the beginning and end of this product name. Where as, when you upload this same file to Google sheets, this quotation on either side is not shown/considered. So it becomes easier in google sheet to manipulate this column, than in Data prep.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to remove `"` from the CSV data and want to put the modified CSV data to Google Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample CSV data?

Answer (score 1):

You can "ignore" these double-quotes, and when running a job, untick the box of "include quotes", then these original quotes shall remain.
Not perfect, but could be a working workaround.